# Maven doesn't find local dependency

Tags: maven

I have a master `pom.xml` which defines two modules, foo (jar) and bar (war).

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.toplevel</groupId>
<artifactId>toplevel</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<name>toplevel-parent</name>   

<modules>
    <module>foo</module>
    <module>bar</module>
</modules>
```

The bar depends on foo:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.toplevel</groupId>
    <artifactId>toplevel</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.toplevel</groupId>
        <artifactId>foo</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

foo doesn't have any dependencies.

I can run `mvn install` from the master (toplevel) level and bar sees the foo dependency. But when I run it from the bar project, I don't see foo:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project bar: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.toplevel:api:war:1.0: Failed to collect dependencies at com.toplevel:foo:jar:1.0: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.toplevel:foo:jar:1.0: Could not find artifact com.toplevel:toplevel:pom:1.0 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]

How can I see a local dependency in my local repo that is on the same level of the pom hierarchy as the one I want to build, without maven trying to go to central? I would like it to install foo if it hasn't yet.

Comment: Note that it's `toplevel` maven can't find, not `foo`.

Comment: @tgdavies, no `toplevel` can find it but not when running mvn at the subproject level

Comment: This works for me. When you run `mvn install` in the toplevel directory do you see something like `[INFO] ------------------------< org.example:toplevel >------------------------
[INFO] Building toplevel 1.0                                              [1/3]
[INFO] --------------------------------[ pom ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ toplevel ---
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\tgdavies\IdeaProjects\so70735467\pom.xml to C:\Users\tgdavies\.m2\repository\org\example\toplevel\1.0\toplevel-1.0.pom`

Comment: Please make a github or alike example project of that setup...